# Why do we need to have the untransformed variable in addition to the time-transformed variable in a Cox model?

Tags: survival, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

For example in the veteran dataset,

```
vfit <-  coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno, veteran)
```

```
vfit3 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno + tt(karno),
data=veteran, 
tt = function(x, t, ...) x * log(t+20))
```

So why do we keep the karno variable on top of the tt(karno)? Can't we just keep tt(karno)? Do we have to do it every time we apply a tt function?

I am sorry for asking this naïve question. My sincere apologies. I would really appreciate it if you could please explain the logic behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't we just keep `tt(karno)`?

We could, but that would be a different model.

Remember that the form chosen for `tt()` in the vignette that provides this example was based on the shape of the coefficient estimates over time, $\beta(t)$, for a model that *started with a time-independent* `karno` *term*. That form thus was intended to capture the *extra* time-dependent variation around a baseline association of `karno` with outcome.

The `tt(karno)` term by itself represents just a time-dependent association of `karno` with outcome, with a single regression coefficient. It doesn't allow for an overall association of `karno` with outcome around which a time-dependent term changes the association. Separate `karno` and `tt(karno)` terms in the formula allow different regression coefficients for the two terms, providing extra flexibility in modeling.

Whether the flexibility in modeling provided by the 2 separate terms leads to a significantly better better model can be evaluated by `anova()`. If you thus compare models having the same `tt(karno)` term with and without the separate `karno` term, you will find a substantially better fit with both terms included.

Including a separate term for the predictor along with its `tt()` transformation is not always appropriate, however. The `coxph` help page shows an example, when you want to use the *current* age as a predictor instead of the age at study entry. In that case, an association of current age with outcome can be modeled with a `tt(age)` term alone. In the help page example, further flexible fitting of current age is provided by including a `pspline()` function:

> tt=function(x,t,...) pspline(x + t/365.25)

In that context, a separate term for `age` isn't included. In general, you have to think about exactly what you wish to model with a `tt()` function; this isn't really different from all the choices one makes about including and transforming predictors while developing a regression model.

Comment: thank you very much for your clarifications. One last query. If I want to report the association of karno with survival, I would report the hazard ratio from the unmodified karno term. But if I want to report the association of karno as a time-dependent variable with survival, I would report the hazard ratio from the tt(karno) term. Is my interpretation correct? My apologies for asking these naïve questions.

Comment: @Biostats if there is a significant time dependence then you shouldn't just be reporting the unmodified `karno` coefficient, as that doesn't completely capture the association of `karno` with outcome. Following Section 4.2 of the [time-dependent vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf), with a `karno` coefficient of $-0.125$ and a `tt(karno)` coefficient of $0.021$ for the above `tt` function, you would report something like: "The coefficient for `karno` varied with time, $\beta_{karno}(t)= -0.125 + 0.021\log(t+20)$."

Comment: Thanks again for your help...why can't I just report 0.021 as the HR for the time-dependent karno or tt(karno) and ignore the unmodified karno?

Comment: @Biostats the model _starts with_ what you call the "unmodified `karno`" coefficient ($-0.125$) and then _adds_ the `tt` term representing the _change over time from that "unmodified" coefficient_. Think about this similarly to fitting a continuous predictor with a second-degree polynomial: would you just report the coefficient for the quadratic term and ignore the linear term to which the quadratic term adds?

Comment: got it...Thanks